# Accessing data from output R program

Tags: r, cut

I have an output generated by the cuts functions which is the one below...lets call this ouput 'data'.

```
cuts: [20,25)
   Time Kilometres
21   20        7.3
22   21        8.4
23   22        9.5
24   23       10.6
25   24       11.7
------------------------------------------------------------ 
cuts: [25,30)
   Time Kilometres
26   25       12.8
27   26       13.9
28   27       15.0
29   28       16.1
30   29       17.2
------------------------------------------------------------ 
cuts: [30,35)
   Time Kilometres
31   30       18.3
32   31       19.4
33   32       20.5
34   33       21.6
35   34       22.7
```

How could I access the data in each cut..like get the kilometres data from cuts:[20,25]..etc I tried doing data$Kilometres...but this does not work...So I basically want a new data frame where I could use the kilometres data seperately for each cut

Comment: I assume you used `by` to generate this. What command using it did you use?

Comment: @sebastian-c, `by` does have a distinct visual output, doesn't it. See original question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15628289/cut-function-in-r-program)

Answer (score 0):

The output of `by` here is a list, so you can use basic list indexing, either by number or name. Using the data from [your question from a few hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15628289/cut-function-in-r-program), and [the answer from Matthew Lundberg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15628513/1270695), we can index as follows:

```
> x[[1]]
  Time Velocity
1  0.0     0.00
2  1.5     1.21
3  3.0     1.26
4  4.5     1.31
> x[["[6,12)"]]
  Time Velocity
5  6.0     1.36
6  7.5     1.41
7  9.0     1.46
8 10.5     1.51
```

You can review the structure of objects in R by using `str`. This is usually useful to help you decide how you can extract certain information. Here's `str(x)`:

```
> str(x)
List of 7
 $ [0,6)  :Classes ‘AsIs’ and 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ Time    : num [1:4] 0 1.5 3 4.5
  ..$ Velocity: num [1:4] 0 1.21 1.26 1.31
 $ [6,12) :Classes ‘AsIs’ and 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ Time    : num [1:4] 6 7.5 9 10.5
  ..$ Velocity: num [1:4] 1.36 1.41 1.46 1.51
 $ [12,18):Classes ‘AsIs’ and 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ Time    : num [1:6] 12 13 14 15 16 17
  ..$ Velocity: num [1:6] 1.56 1.61 1.66 1.71 1.76 1.81
 $ [18,24):Classes ‘AsIs’ and 'data.frame': 5 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ Time    : num [1:5] 18 19 20 21 22.5
  ..$ Velocity: num [1:5] 1.86 1.91 1.96 2.01 2.06
 $ [24,30):Classes ‘AsIs’ and 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ Time    : num [1:4] 24 25.5 27 28.5
  ..$ Velocity: num [1:4] 2.11 2.16 2.21 2.26
 $ [30,36):Classes ‘AsIs’ and 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ Time    : num [1:4] 30 31.5 33 34.5
  ..$ Velocity: num [1:4] 2.31 2.36 2.41 2.42
 $ [36,42):Classes ‘AsIs’ and 'data.frame': 1 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ Time    : num 36
  ..$ Velocity: num 2.43
 - attr(*, "dim")= int 7
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
  ..$ cuts: chr [1:7] "[0,6)" "[6,12)" "[12,18)" "[18,24)" ...
 - attr(*, "call")= language by.data.frame(data = mydf, INDICES = cuts, FUN = I)
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "by"
```

From this we can see that we have a named list of seven items, and each list contains a `data.frame`. Thus, if we wanted a vector of just the "Velocity" variable (second column) for the third interval, we would use something like:

```
> x[[3]][[2]]
[1] 1.56 1.61 1.66 1.71 1.76 1.81
```